# how to use javascript variable in script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, razor, razor-pages

I want to Use TypeID in another tag. would please help me?

```html
<script>
  $(ItemType).change(function () {
  var TypeID = $(this).val();
  });
</script>
 
<div class="form-group">
    @if(TypeID==1){
      do something
    } else {
      do something
    }
<div>
```

Comment: C# variables run server side. Javascript variable run client side. You can't mix them like this. `@if(TypeID==1){` won;t work

Comment: it is razor page. you can use C# in razor

Comment: Yes. But `TypeID` is a javascript variable.  `@if(TypeID==1){}` should throw error